# Codeigniter 3 and codeigniter-restserver not working

Tags: codeigniter-3, codeigniter-restserver

We are using Codeigniter 3 and codeigniter-restserver in our new project. we have configured all the settings for Codeigniter-restserver.

But we are getting error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined property: Login::$format
Filename: controllers/REST_Controller.php
Line Number: 728
```

Login is controller name which is extending REST_Controller.

Please help us with this..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I load both Format.php and Rest_Controller.php into a controller. 
After have a quick glance at Format.php, it appears to be a standalone format conversion helper. 
Try to just load Rest_Controller.php and see if your problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing using Composer to avoid errors:

```
composer require chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver
```

Hope this helps.